# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Firefox console output:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

I have been trying everything I could. Please can someone help me out on the version and set of dependencies for maven project; I am using Java.

Comment: What is selenium version ? Try upgrading your Selenium WebDriver to version 2.43.0.

Comment: Are you using firefox 47.0?

Comment: Yes I am using firefox 47,0. Here is my POM XML:<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.53.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
   <version>2.53.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have and I am still having same issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now working via this link :                                                                     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb5L62rGb-I#t=465.233396

Answer (score 0):

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2bb1d1a9ab8cacc21418b54e7e0ab080ae9daa31/68747470733a2f2f7777772e657665726e6f74652e636f6d2f6c2f41434d4a64747a315343394e39614e595f647762673639414649695171613876746738422f696d6167652e706e67

Visit the link and check the compatible versions of selenium with firefox and install the browser according to that.Hope this will help you.